Joshua stopping the sun
Note: I'm not an expert in science.
I have been wondering for a while what does it mean that Joshua made the Sun stand still?
Since the Earth revolves around the Sun, it makes more sense to say that the Earth stood still. How to understand this?

Type “Geocentric” in the search bar. Many questions and answers have already addressed this.

According to the general theory of relativity the sun orbits the earth and the earth orbits the sun. Scientists use a heliocentric view just for simplicities sake.

@Shababnik That's incorrect. Already before relativity it was known that both the earth and sun orbit their joint center of mass (called a barycenter)

@DoubleAA General relativity allows any frame of reference to be chosen as a “center”, and earth can be the center if one adopts a non inertial frame of reference. It's more complicated and not the natural choice but in theory it's not mad. I think Y DJ went through this recently in another similar Q&A? The idea of a barycenter in our solar system with multiple planets is not so simple either, but I'm just being pedantic now

@RabbiKaii Sure but in that frame the sun still isn't orbiting earth.

@DoubleAA it is going around the earth. I don't think the Torah was talking about how

@RabbiKaii The torah never took a position. Most people till recently thought the geocentric view was the single correct one. We now know they (including Rashbi, Rambam, the Alter Rebbe, etc.) were all wrong and no view is the single correct one. The rest is word games.

@DoubleAA if all celestial bodies orbit a barycenter in relation to each other. This would answer the question - we are simply talking from our perspective.

@Shababnik if we are orbiting a barycenter, the sun is still not orbiting us

@RabbiKaii exactly it doesn't matter. We're talking from our perspective since theres no objective reality

From a scientific viewpoint, if the earth stood still that would mean it stopped rotating which would look like the sun stopped its arc across the sky from our viewpoint on earth. If that were the case, everything on the surface of earth would fly eastward at some significant velocity. Extremely chaotic.

The Tanach always speaks about "science" from our perspective. So do we:

The sun rises
The moon sets

Similarly, you would have said that the sun stopped setting on that amazing day. You wouldn't say that the earth stopped spinning, since you cannot tell that the earth is spinning around itself and around the sun.
Ever seen a photo of the people watching the earth slipping away into darkness as it rotates away from the sun? Um, yes, sunset.
Chazal call this דיברה תורה כלשון בני אדם - the Torah speaks the way we do. It even has its own Wikipedia entry in Hebrew.

That is not an explanation.

@YDJ The question was how to understand it. The way to understand it is as a figure of speech representing how the phenomena appear to average humans.

@DoubleAA the way phenomena appear is subjective. Understanding is objective.

@YDJ "Since the Earth revolves around the Sun, it makes more sense to say that the Earth stood still. How to understand this?" It sounds pretty clear...

@YDJ I would say relative, rather than subjective. Which frame of reference is the Torah talking in? It is objectively talking in the frame of reference of man, according to this answer, therefore I don't see any problem with this answer?

@RabbiKaii sorry, I do not understand this type of reasoning. Can we live in peace?

@YDJ it's never personal dw. I'm always interested in your way of thinking, even if I sometimes challenge it. Challenge is good

There is a principle from the Baal Shem Tov that the world is recreated from nothing every instant. The question is, why is this attributed to the Baal Shem Tov? Isn't this based on tefilla, clear chazal and even pesukim? What is the Chiddush of the Baal Shem Tov?
The Chiddush is that each time the world is created, it is created from nothing. Meaning, cause and effect is just an illusion maintained by God, because His Will is the cause of everything. Indeed, this illusion that causes lead to predictable effects is because that's how Hashem basically desires the world to run. Therefore, He personally sees to it that each instant logically follows from the last, at least to the limits of our perceptibility in most scenarios.
The reason I mention this is because when we say "you can't say the sun stopped, because the earth goes round the sun, not the other way around!" we are speaking as though Hashem isn't actually making the earth go round the sun, each instant, purely based on His desire alone, but rather He spun up the earth and threw it into an orbit, letting go of it and letting it continue on its own, and only "stops" it when He desires. This is just patently not true, according to the Baal Shem Tov.
Therefore, who are we to question His statement that the sun stopped? All we have is an illusion with which to challenge it!

We certainly do not want to live with an illusion about events in Jewish history. Even if it is above our heads at present.

@YDJ I use the term illusion very specifically. Reality is real, and what has happened has happened, really. It's the cause and effect process that is the illusion.
